# How to navigate to parent of subtask in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

In YouTrack, an issue can be a subtask of only a single "parent" issue.

How can we quickly navigate via keyboard to this parent from the "full issue view" of the subtask?

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut for this operation now, but here's the respective feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-28541.